# What does the built in class named list do?

Tags: list, class, oop, python-3.7

I'm reading an OOP book and I'm at the inheritance chapter. There is a sample code that I don't understand. A class inherited a class named list but it wasn't defined. So I checked by typing list on my editor and it was blue. So that mean it is a class. I tried searching on Bing to see what the class did, but I only get documentations and tutorials on python list. Here's the code:

```
class ContactList(list):
    def search(self, name):
        '''Return all contacts that contain the search value in their name.'''
        matching_contacts = []
        for contact in self:
            if name in contact.name:
                matching_contacts.append(contact)
        return matching_contacts


class Contact:
    all_contacts = ContactList()

    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        Contact.all_contacts.append(self)

        print(self.all_contacts)


class Supplier(Contact):
    def order(self, order):
        print("If this were a real system we would send "
        "'{}' order to '{}'".format(order, self.name))
```

Thanks!

Comment: [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list) is a standard type in python and you can extend it in your own classes.

Comment: Have you tried to read the (excellent) [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/)? Especially [the `list` class documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) should be useful.

Comment: But what happens when you extend it?

Comment: Then you get a new class which behaves like `list`, plus whatever you add to it in the extending class.

Comment: And I can't find the list documentation

Comment: @JiberJaber It's like extending any other class.

Comment: Where can I see the code for list? I want to know what it does

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list